# My program lags on >100 character key

Tags: java

My class generating passwords lags on >100 length key, and throws an exception.
Here is my Key Generator class:

```
package dialogs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class AdvKey {
    byte[] concatenateByteArrays(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        byte[] result = new byte[a.length + b.length]; 
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length); 
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length); 
        return result;
    } 
    private byte[] arr=null;
    private byte[][] characters={"!@#$%^&*()_+=".getBytes(), 
                                  "1234567890".getBytes(), 
                                  "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".getBytes(), 
                                  "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM".getBytes()};
    public AdvKey(int size, boolean specials, boolean numbers, boolean charactersb, boolean bigCharacters) throws IOException {
        byte[] characters1 = new byte[512];
        characters1="1234567890".getBytes();
        if(specials){
            characters1=concatenateByteArrays(characters1, characters[0]);
        }
        if(numbers){
            characters1=concatenateByteArrays(characters1, characters[1]);
        }
        if(charactersb){
            characters1=concatenateByteArrays(characters1, characters[2]);
        }
        if(bigCharacters){
            characters1=concatenateByteArrays(characters1, characters[3]);
        }
        arr=new byte[size];
        Random r = new Random();
        r.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i]=characters1[r.nextInt((characters1.length - 0) + 1) + 0];
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return new String(arr);
    }
}
```

And this is exception thrown by that code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at dialogs.AdvKey.<init>(AdvKey.java:37)
    (...)
```

That exception occurs when in for that generates random numbers, and take it's id from characters1 array.

I execute it using

```
String output = new AdvKey(200, true, true, true, true).toString();
```

Comment: You actually subtracted _zero_? And then added it again? o.0

Comment: Your bug is probably that you want to subtract one here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the line you must change

```
arr[i]=characters1[r.nextInt((characters1.length - 0) + 1) + 0];
```

To

```
arr[i]=characters1[r.nextInt(characters1.length)];
```

`Random#nextInt` will generate numbers from `0` to the `input -1`. If you're using `characters1.length + 1`, you're asking the program to generate numbers from `0` to `characters1.length`. Since the length of an array is always `lastIndex + 1`, you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

### Example

If the length of your array is 84, you were actually asking to generate numbers from 0 to 84 (85 elements - thus one too many).

---

PS : What's up with the `-0` and `+0`? :)